# Does C# have a builtinway of converting binary number to array of bit powers ( e.g. 0b1101 -> {0, 2, 3} )?

Tags: c#, binary, set

(Edit - preface: I am implementing an iterable through all subsets of given size.
For getting the next combination, I am using Gosper's hack to quickly get the 0/1 vector of lexicographically next combination. Now I need to quickly map the vector of combination to the array of elements from my set. Luckily, the elements are the very same as the powers of individual bits, and I am wondering if C# doesn't have fast shortcut for that.)

If I get K-th subset (in lexicographical order) of numbers 0 - (N-1), the bits in binary representation of K are telling me which elements should I choose. What is the most elegant way of checking which bits are set and making a subset (array) based on these?

Something like:

```
var BitPowers = new List<int>();
for(int i = 0; i<N; ++i)
{
  if((K & (1<<i)) != 0)
  { 
   BitPowers.Add(i);
  }
}
return BitPowers.ToArray();
```

would probably suffice, but is it the best way? I guess bit operations are quick, but as the number of possible sets is exponential, optimizing this function as much as I can would be ideal.

Comment: Nothing built-in, but you are free to write your own and post it to code-review to see if the folks there can improve on it. - Btw: to 'optimize' you need to decide on what to optimize for: Speed, space, elegance, maintainability...? - Also: _ the number of possible sets is exponential_ not sure what that means..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no .NET builtin API to do such thing, as I know.

**The Linq magic**

You can write this compact code in one assignment, but less optimized for speed:

```
int value = 0b10110010;

var BitPowers = Convert.ToString(value, 2)
                       .Reverse()
                       .Select((bit, index) => new { index, bit })
                       .Where(v => v.bit == '1').Select(v => v.index);

foreach ( int index in BitPowers )
  Console.WriteLine(index);
```

It converts the integer to a binary representation of a string, inverted to have good indexes from left to right, then it selects a pair of (bit, index), then it filters on those that are defined, then it selects the indexes for create the enumerable list.

*Output*

```
1
4
5
7
```

**Compromise between elegance and speed**

You can simplify your loop using a BitArray instance.

Perhaps it is the closest "builtin" way you ask for:

```
var bits = new BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(value));
for ( int index = 0; index < bits.Length; index++ )
  if ( bits[index] )
    BitPowers.Add(index);
```

Comment: Pretty cool, runs 2 times faster. 
(Tested on 1 000 000 random numbers, 200 times)